# Ash profile/configuration file

Tags: profile, ash

I am looking for a way to customize Ash sessions with my own sets of `alias`es and whatnots. What is the Ash equivalent of Bash's `bashrc` files?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Ash first reads the following files (if they exist):

- System: `/etc/profile`
- User: `~/.profile`

Comment: Provided that it is run as the login shell, which isn't the default (e.g. in Alpine Linux / Docker)

Comment: @JakubHolý did you find a way to run profile script for non-login shell?

Comment: @DavidLukac - See my other Answer here for non-login shells.

Comment: What do you mean by "first" reads these files? Will it do something else afterwards?

Comment: Those are equivalent of .profile, the question is about .bashrc.

Answer (score 17):

A non-login 'ash' or 'dash'-based shell may also 'source' a file if that file's full path is contained in the environment variable ENV (or perhaps SHINIT).

So if you set that somehow (Maybe in your ~/.profile, or some other 'overarching' environment control), then any future forked shells will run that script. Very handy for non-login cases.

Example:
In your .profile, something like:

```bash
ENV=$HOME/.ashrc; export ENV
. $ENV
```

Or if you like being explicit:

```bash
ENV=/home/kwest/.ashrc; export ENV
# File in 'ENV' will be sourced for future shells. Also source it for this login shell:
. $ENV
```

Note that you should set ENV to a full explicit path, as the above will do. Don't use '~'.

It's hard to find explicit documentation on this for ash/dash, but it is confirmed to work on busybox-w32 (running on Windows). In fact it's hard to find good documentation on the featureset of ash at all.

UPDATE: There are a range of ash variants in the wild. 'ENV' may not work with all of them. There is some info on variants here: [https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/ash/)

There is a suggestion in there that some ash variants may use 'SHINIT' in place of ENV.

Comment: Not working for me under Alpine 3.7.

Comment: @knite Busybox's Ash (used by Alpine) uses [ENV](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/shell/ash.c?h=1_29_3#n14189).

Comment: Has the ENV or SHINIT variable just to be set or to be set to a specific value? I am trying to force docker to read .profile in /root/.profile without explicitly starting with /bin/sh -l

Comment: @Leon - ENV (or maybe SHINIT) needs to contain the full path of the file to load/source. But this is only for startup of ‘ash’ shell variants - not the common sh or bash shells.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what should be set in `ENV`?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati - Added in post.

Answer (score 0):

Some year after the question on alipline 3.17 I figured out a solution (may not be the best, any comment welcome).

- Edit as root `/etc/profile` to add at the end just before the `unset script` this line:

  ```shell
  . $HOME/.profile
  ```
- Then create a `.profile` in your home dir as described before like this:

  ```shell
  ENV=$HOME/.ashrc; export ENV
  . $ENV
  ```

Then you can create a `.ashrc` in your home dir to set you aliases or other stuff.